# Windows converted all files to .lwsdnrl format?

Tags: windows-xp, filesystems, ntfs, file-format

I have some problems with Windows XP. After scanning the whole file system with anti-virus program, each and every file got an extension ".lwsdnrl" ? Even if I try to open the file with the appropriate program, it fails. For example, a file called "myFile.pdf" got converted to "myFile.PDF.lwsdnrl". In addition on every file when you click on properties there is the following text : "This file came from another computer and might be blocked" and an "unblock" button. However, I found out how to unblock all files globally, bit still they look damaged and can not be opened. For example:

- openning PDF file fails with error, saying the file is of unrecognized type or it is damaged
- openning .doc file just fails
- openning .xls file succeeds but just a meaningless sequence of symbols is shown on the screen
- openning .jpeg file says "no preview available"

I read about [Microsoft streams](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897440.aspx) and executed:

```
streams -s -d *.*
```

in folders with damaged files and a lot of streams were deleted, but that didn't help

Any help how to restore my information will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: What anti-virus program was it?

Comment: It was eset NOD 32

Comment: What was the reason to scan your system with a virusscanner? The reason I am asking, is because it sounds you have a randsom virus on your system, that converted all your files, and the virus scan was ran after and you only then noticed it. If this is the case, you cannot get these files back and you have to resort on your backups. Also, you should definitely upgrade to a more modern OS because windows XP has too many security holes so getting a virus infection will happen sooner or later.

Comment: opened .cab file attached to email from trusted user

Comment: then tell the 'trusted user' he's being used as part of a botnet & hope he's not also still on XP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are victim of ransomware. And based on the contemporary situation with this software you can do two things:

1. pay the ransom and pray you will get the private key to decode the files
2. restore from backup/forget about these files

Comment: I never understood ransomware. What incentive do criminals have to restore your files after you give them money. Maybe for the scam to work, you have to do it so the next victim can you will be an honorable criminal. WTF right?